# Putting Model/Object on Http Get URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, api

I need to make a http get call and I was wondering if it is possible to have a model as the parameter, so I wouldn't have to have 12 parameters.

Javascript

```
 function doSomething(){
     vm.model = createModel();
     window.open('ExportFile/' + vm.model, '_blank','');
 }

 function createModel() {
     return {
        name: vm.name,
        type: vm.type,
        status: vm.status,
        // etc...
     };
 }
```

Controller

```
 public virtual ActionResult ExportFile(Filters filter)
 {
     // query database and return file
 }
```

Model

```
 public class Filters
 {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string Type {get; set;}
     public string Status {get; set;}
     // etc... 
 }
```

Comment: You can pass a param which will store your serialized model. Serialization of the object could be done using `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Something like this - `window.open('ExportFile/?model=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({filter: vm.model})), '_blank','');`

Comment: @Vitaliy That didn't get an error but the model was null in the controller

Comment: It's another question. You've asked how to put a model, now you are asking how to parse it. I'm not a C# specialist but I can see that JS model and server-side model have different properties (name and Name, type and Type). Probably the problem is here. If not - please update your question and ask not only how to modify an URL but also how to handle it then :)

Comment: You should be doing this as a post. Apart from the ugly query string it creates, you could exceed the query string limit and throw and exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not completly sure about what you're trying to achieve but have you tried converting the object to a JSON string? as in:

```
function createModel() {
     return JSON.stringify({
        name: vm.name,
        type: vm.type,
        status: vm.status,
        // etc...
     });
 }
```

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:

'The RouteData must contain an item named 'action' with a non-empty string value'

Comment: Do you have an entry named 'action' in the model object you are constructing and is it non empty? seems like your backend is expecting data you are not sending

Comment: no there is no entry for action. Right now I am using the same model that works on a post call to the controller.

Comment: Maybe your backend determines the action automatically from the POST request and not from GET. You may have to set it manually on your model. You should look at what gets passed with a POST or look at the backend's code handling the incoming requests